# Do reputation points on deleted/closed/locked count?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

I'm doing a project where I have to mine through some stackoverflow data and I was wondering if the reputation that a user earns/loses on a question that is deleted/closed/locked counts towards the user's overall reputation or are they discarded as soon as the original question's status is changed to one of the above?

So if for example I originally have 10 reputation points and I answer a question and my answer gets upvoted twice and now have 30 points. If this question is deleted in the future, will my reputation go back to 10 points?

From browsing a few posts related to this, it seems that reputation on deleted/closed questions does count, but i am not sure with respect to deleted questions. Also it seems there have been a few bug fixes in this area over the past. So I was hoping someone can give a definitive answer to this.

As an aside , I would also appreciate it if someone could tell me what happens to the reputation points earned/lost on deleted answers as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reputation on deleted posts is reversed unless the following two conditions are true:

- The post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days.
- The post has a score of at least 3.

Comment: thanks...is it the same for closed and locked as well and could you tell me if this has always been the case or was there a change to the policy recently?

Comment: Closed and locked posts will not reverse any reputation effects, only deletion. Long ago, reputation effects were *not automatically reversed*. You always kept reputation until you triggered a manual reputation recalculation on your account. This was changed a while ago and reputation is now automatically recalculated within 5 minutes of a deletion. Shortly after that these two rules were added.

Comment: the data that I have is from July 2012 so will this be from after the rule changes were implemented?

Comment: The [original announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes) was posted in February 2012.